# How to Automatically Assign Owner to New Generated Lead through Zapier?

Tags: zapier, formidable, lead

I am currently working on setting up an automation process for my business where new leads generated through Zapier are automatically assigned to a designated owner within our team. I am using Zapier to generate leads, but I am having difficulty with the assignment process.

I am hoping to get some guidance on how to automate the process of assigning an owner to a newly generated lead in Zapier. Is there a specific Zap or integration that I need to use to achieve this?

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

[image]